When using query parameters in a Go Router URL, it will navigate to the initial route
I'm using Go Router to implement deep linking for a specific page. For this page, I'm creating a URL with both query parameters and path variables. However, it's navigating to the initial route in my application instead of the intended page.
The URL I'm creating is as follows:
Deep link: https://{myhostname}/?key={key}/pathparam
 GoRoute(
        name: RouteNameConstants.initialpage,
        path: "/",
        builder: (context, state) {
          return InitialPage();
           
        }),

 GoRoute(
      name:RouteNameConstants.queryparamspage,
      path: "/:pathparam",
      builder: (context, state) {
        String? key = state.queryParams["key"];
            var  pathparam= state.params['pathparam'];
             
        return  QueryParamsPage( key : key    , pathparam : pathparam ,);
      },
    ),




That's not how you use pathparams. the query params always come last. You should use https://{myhostname}/pathparam?key={key}
